# ConstraintLayout - width of view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, width, android-constraintlayout

I want to set `layout_width` (width) of one view pager equal to another (or start and end alignment for both should be equals) in XML file.

I tried following code but it seems not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.yyy.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpTop"
        android:layout_width="@+id/vpCenter"  // Here trying to assign width equal to orange view
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpCenter"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpBottom"
        android:layout_width="@+id/vpCenter" // Here trying to assign width equal to orange view
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is preview:

[image]

I want width of both green view pager equal to orange view pager. 
Note: Orange view pager has fixed `layout_width` = 200. I don't want to set fixed width (200) for both green view pager but I want width of orange view should be assigned to both green views. (Start and end alignment should be equals)

I want something like this:

[image]

How can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something as you wanna have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpCenter"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpBottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vpCenter" <!--key attributes-->
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vpCenter" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output of this xml is:
[image: output]

Comment: Happy to help you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.yyy.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpCenter"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpBottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vpCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vpCenter" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort :)